# Matching two distinct images with similar SURF features matlab

Tags: matlab

We are working upon gesture to text conversion using matlab and want the input gesture from user to be mapped with a predefined database. Using detectsurffeatures function, we extract the features, but proper matching is not taking place unless input is a part of the reference image

How to map the features the pairs like...
[input hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBAxR.jpg) and [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQRh9.jpg)

We are not getting any error, yet the images are not mapped.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: I was going to add the images for you, but they are clearly someone else's copyright with watermarks. Could you please supply some images where you have rights to share them (technically placing them in a SO question puts them under Creative Commons license, so you need to be owner or they are already CC)?

Comment: In addition, if you could show briefly how you are using `detectsurffeatures` and attempting the database match, it would allow someone to show where you are going wrong, which is easier to do so you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I just uplaoded the picture to show an example of our database... originally its made up of 20+ images in a single frame.